# Naive Bayes Classifier: Only get 30-40% accuracy on iris data set

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, naivebayes, data-science

I'm trying to implement Naive Bayes Classifier in python for the last few days with the iris data set from UCI (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris). When trying to classify 100 random samples i get only 30-40% accuracy. I think my probability function is right because I tested it with the example from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Examples)

Now here's what I do:

- I load the data
- I divide the data into 3 classes
- I calculate the mean and variance for each class

Then for 100 random samples I:

- calculate the probability for each feature to belong to a class
- Calculate the posterior numerator by multiplying each probability for that class
- Store the values in a list and get the index of the highest value
- compare the highest value index to the real index (Check if prediction is right)

And somehow I only get 30-40%, am I doing something wrong?

If you want to see the code, it's here: http://pastebin.com/sUYm97qi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LOL -- you wrote very concise/clean code so I was very confused until I saw the very end.

You were comparing `classes[max_index]`, the class name of the prediction with `y[max_index]`, the max index-th instance label value.

Try changing your code to

```
if(classes[max_index] == y[q]):
    corr += 1
```

You should get around 96%

Comment: @Lagastic but it still give around 47% if I choose only 50 values in test set ?

Comment: @Tejendra You are right, that is due to an error I made in reporting the results, because I put 100 as test samples, the corr variable will be the amount of correct answers per 100. Divide corr by the amount of test samples and you should get around 96-98% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the classbuilding part

```
class1 = X[0:50]
class2 = X[51:100]
class3 = X[101:150]
```

should be

```
class1 = X[0:50]
class2 = X[50:100]
class3 = X[100:150]
```

to not overlap. Don't how much it matters.
Anyway - try and give some feedback, what numbers you get then.

Comment: Changed it, the accuracy range still ranges between 30 and 40%.

Comment: Are there any other things I could try and change to see if it improves? Am i maybe doing something important wrong in my implementation?